# Sorting array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I sort array of hashes if I have pre-determined order I have an array that needs to be sorted like this :

```
   array =  [{:attr_name=>:phone, :attr_value=>30}, {:attr_name=>:name, :attr_value=>20}, {:attr_name=>:similarity, :attr_value=>0}, {:attr_name=>:weight, :attr_value=>50}]
```

and I've got a hash based on which I want it to be sorted :

```
pre_sorted = {
            :name => 0,
            :phone => 1,
            :weight=> 2,
            :similarity => 3
        }
```

After sorting my array should look like this :

```
[{:attr_name=>:name, :attr_value=>20}, {:attr_name=>:phone, :attr_value=>30}, {:attr_name=>:weight, :attr_value=>50}, {:attr_name=>"similarity", :attr_value=>0}]
```

I've looked at the ruby sort and sort by docs and found related questions on So but couldn't figure it out because I'm just starting with rails.

Comment: Why is `similarity` a string in your array, but a symbol in the `pre_sorted` hash?

Comment: @sepp2k thanks that was a typo on my part, I've corrected it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sort an array by a given criterion, you can use `sort_by`. In your case you want to sort by the entry in the `pre_sorted` hash, so:

```
array.sort_by do |hash|
  pre_sorted[ hash[:attr_name] ]
end
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, when I use your method I get the error `comparison of Fixnum with nil failed`

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow That happens if the block given to `sort_by` returns `nil`, which in this case would happen if `pre_sorted` did not contain a value for (at least) one of the `attr_name`s. However given the code in the question, that should not (and in fact does not - I just tried it) occur.

Answer (score 1):

Array#sort accepts a block of code to use for the comparison: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort

```
array.sort{|a,b| pre_sorted[a[:attr_value]] <=> pre_sorted[b[:attr_value]]}
```

Comment: The second you start having to dive into an object or structure to access the values you want to compare, you should look at the cost required to get there, and think seriously about using `sort_by`. To understand why, read about the "[Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)", which is what [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) uses. Randall Schwartz has [a page discussing it](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col64.html) for additional reading.

Comment: Huh. I wasn't aware there was an inherent optimization in sort_by. Ruby never fails to impress me.

Comment: It's not a Ruby optimization, it's a benefit of the transform.